# Is it correct to say "I didn't study this chapter in details"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

My professor wants to ask me some questions about a chapter.

I want to tell him I didn't study it in details.

What should I say?

Answer (score 2):

*I'm sorry, but I did not study that chapter in detail*.

Also, the moderators of this forum would suggest that you post this question in [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), as this forum is for serious English questions.